# Android Pause / Resume

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

Just looking at this documentation about Activity Lifecycle
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

it seems to me the **onResume** callback is not really a real resume. Because it will run if

a. Activity is just created, even if it was not paused. 
b. Activity was paused and then it's resumed.

I am sending a user to another activity to do stuff, and depending on what the user did on those other activities, when they return, I need to decide whether to reload the app manifest. However, I don't even wanna check if the app was not paused at all! (ie. the user just opened the activity)

Is there a better way to track if the user is really resuming other than creating a variable in onPause that I will check when the user returns?

Comment: Where are you loading the data in the first place? You are worried about whether to "reload" the data, which implies that the data was already loaded. If you are loading the data in `onCreate()`, move that to `onResume()`, and now it will handle both the initial load and any required reload operation. Or, consider [a more structured app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html), where updates are pushed into the activity via reactive programming (`LiveData`, RxJava, etc.).

Comment: Loading data from a third party api. The other activities do stuff like update api data. However, I don't want to reload data if the user returns and hasn't done any changes.

Comment: LiveData is interesting. I am going to read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a boolean flag in your activity:

```
boolean hasBeenPaused = false;
```

Now in your onPause(), set this to true:

```
public void onPause(){
   hasBeenPaused = true;
}
```

Since your onResume gets called whether or not the app was previously paused, you can now check the boolean and know if it's a fresh start onResume or post pause onResume

```
public void onResume(){

   if(hasBeenPaused){
      //onPause was called
      //May be because of home button press, recents opened, another activity opened or a call etc... 
   }else{
      //this is a call just after the activity was created
   }

}
```

If you want to persist, you can even save this variable inside onSaveInstanceState and get the saved state in your onCreate

Comment: Ah, i see. I was hoping there is a better way, but that will be fine too. Really wish the onResume method wasn't misleading lol. I had done so much logic thinking it's really a resume.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately it's the way the life cycle is set, no way to circumvent the cycle... Please accept the answer if this helps.

Comment: yea. It says i have to wait 5min to accept. I will tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely against setting the variable in onPause and want to ensure that a change was made before reloading the data then set a variable in your API calls that triggers a reload when the user comes back to the activity. Depending on your application structure you could even do the reload before hitting onResume in the activity.

Also be aware that onResume will be called if you're in a fragment and provide a popup (such as an activity indicator).

Comment: Just wondering, will that variable hold its value as long as the activity is alive in the background? or might it get reset if there configuration changes etc...?

Comment: That depends on where you set it. If you want it to persist you can set it at a class level in your starting activity and it will persist as long as that activity is alive, but would require a method for passing that variable back to the starting activity. A simpler approach for just storing a bool would be using shared preferences. A more elaborate approach would be to broadcast an event when the API call finishes and have an event listener that starts the data fetch when the event happens. This will allow you to refresh the data beforehand and would stop your users from waiting as long.